# WHERE condition on angularJS forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to apply a `WHERE` condition in an `angularJS` `forEach` loop?

```
angular.forEach(i.menu_modifier_groups, function(group) {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach(group.menu_modifier_items, function(item) {
        count += item.selected ? 1 : 0;
    });
    if (count == group.max_selection_points) {
        IsAllSelected = true;
    } else {
        //if one item failed All select do return false
        IsAllSelected = false;
    }
});
```

I want to apply a `WHERE` condition to tell `angular` the items to loop through.

`i.menu_modifier_groups WHERE group.min_selection_points > 0` for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter to get filtered data. I.e. like I .menu_modifier_groups.filter ( function...)

Please find below a small working example.

```
var arr = [];

var obj = {x: 54, y: 10};
arr.push(obj);
var obj1 = {x: 14, y: 10};
arr.push(obj1);

var finalAccrualRows = arr.filter(function (object) {
                        return object.x===54?false:true;
                    });
alert(finalAccrualRows.length);
```

So for your case it would be like

```
var finalGroups = i.menu_modifier_groups.filter(function (group) {
return (group.min_selection_points > 0)?true:false;
});
```

It is simply a list.filter() function to filter the list, Hope this should help you.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: Angularjs provides var filteredItems = $filter('filter')(list, expression)  which will return filtered list. So you can use this.